# QSslSocket error when SSL is NOT used

Tags: qt, ssl, qsslsocket

I have noticed this output in two of my Qt applications that use QNetworkRequest to load some data from outside over QNeworkRequest :

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
```

One example of the request which causes these warnings to appear is

```
QNetworkReply reply = m_nam->get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=2835297&mode=xml")));
```

I am reasonably sure that there is no TLS/SSL involved in any of the queries, all are plain HTTP. The messages appear always after the first request is dispatched, regardless of URL. **I have no intention to ude SSL at all, there is no mention of SSL in the code**, which means I can't ignore the warnings programatically.

My setup is Windows 7 64 bit, MSVC2013 and MinGW, Qt 5.3.2. The messages appear regardless of the compiler used. No OpenSSL or other SSL development libraries are installed.

And the question is: **How do I get rid of these warnings?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

These are just from qWarning() call when OpenSSL functions are resolved. It is not trying to call these functions, just resolving them. Calling unresolved functions would result in `QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ...` warning instead.

The warning is result of OpenSSL functions being resolved at runtime by a call to `QSslSocket::supportsSsl()` static in `QNetworkAccessManager::supportedSchemesImplementation()` that returns supported schemas --- `http` and, if SSL supported `https`.

You have few options about these warnings,

1. ignore them because you don't want or need SSL anyway
2. recompile Qt with `-no-openssl` passed to `configure`
3. ship OpenSSL so functions are resolved and `https` becomes available - probably not what you want

Comment: Great explanation, thank you! Usually I prefer not to plainly ignore what _my_ program outputs, but it looks like the optimal solution here.

Comment: In addition, you can also disable those messages by setting environmental variable QT_LOGGING_RULES=qt.network.ssl.warning=false

Comment: that's not good though,I better see the warning and ignore them, than hiding them, later I maybe in trouble and I won't know what's going on, warnings helps to debug.

Comment: How do I "ship OpenSSL"?

Answer (score 5):

Can be disabled related warning messages with `QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules("qt.network.ssl.w arning=false");`

Comment: Interesting that it works even with the extra space. And it works without the ".warning" altogether. Go figure...

Answer (score 4):

We occasionally had customers getting very similar warning messages but the software was also crashing.

```
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
QMutex: destroying locked mutex
```

We determined it was because, although we weren't using SSL either, the program found a copy of OpenSSL on the customer's computer and tried interfacing with it.  The version it found was too old though ([from Qt 5.2 onwards](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html) v1.0.0 or later is required).

Our solution was to distribute the OpenSSL DLLs along with our application (~1.65 MB).  The alternative is to compile Qt from scratch without OpenSSL support.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [QSslSocket::ignoreSslErrors](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsslsocket.html#ignoreSslErrors-2)?

Comment: I don't use QSslSocket, I have no object to use it on. There is no intention to use SSL at all. I'll edit this into the original answer to make it clear.

Comment: I tried it, and it does not fix the issue: warnings still appears, program still freezing.