# HTTPS Basic Authentication for TagniFi fails in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, https, basic-authentication

I am trying to retrieve data from TagniFi using basic HTTPS authentication but unable to complete the request. According to the [TagniFi doc](http://docs.tagnifi.com/article/28-authentication), the authentication key is supposed to be passed as the username in the query URL ignoring the password. So I tried the following but they do not work as expected;

> > Omitting the password and the semicolon of the HTTPS basic authentication format
> >     i.e. `https://<username>:<password>@<website URL>`
> >     `"https://<my_authentication_key>@api.tagnifi.com/fundamentals?company=aapl&tag=revenue&period_type=quarter&fiscal_year=2014&fiscal_quarter=3"`
> >
> > I tried the following also with the semi-colon
> >     `"https://<my_authentication_key>:@api.tagnifi.com/fundamentals?company=aapl&tag=revenue&period_type=quarter&fiscal_year=2014&fiscal_quarter=3"`

[TagniFi doc example](http://docs.tagnifi.com/article/30-search-tagnifi-fundamentals) says the URL should as the following with the basic authentication;

> > `https://api.tagnifi.com/fundamentals?company=aapl&statement=income_statement&period_type=quarter&fiscal_year=2014&fiscal_quarter=3`

The warnings I get in Qt is the following;

```
`qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_set_psk_client_callback
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_client_method
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_client_method
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_1_server_method
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve TLSv1_2_server_method
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_select_next_proto
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated
   qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function        SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated`
```

What am I doing wrong? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Basic Authentication problem. The QT library needs to be compiled with OpenSSL support.

Here are two helpful SO answers:

1.) [Use OpenSSL in Qt C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39480724/use-openssl-in-qt-c#39497754)

2.) [QSslSocket error when SSL is NOT used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361145/qsslsocket-error-when-ssl-is-not-used)

Comment: Hello, Dave thanks for your answer. This may be stupid question but just wanted to clarify. Is it possible to use HTTPS without openSSL support? Because the app I make cannot be used in all parts of the world if uses a strong crytographic software like openSSL. Please advice.